# Virtualization Advice Sought

Tags: virtualbox

I have been a Virtualbox user on Ubuntu user for years.  However, for the past year plus, I have had a problem with my vdi / file systems becoming mysteriously corrupt and I, nor vbox support can figure out why.

I am currently using Vbox6.1 installed from Ubuntu repository on Ubuntu 20.04.

**Things that I have tried:**

1.) I have used clonezilla and other tools to copy my data to new vdi disk, but the corrupt file system re-emerges within a a few days.

2.) I have booted my host system from ubuntu live CD and used smarttools to verify that host systems hybrid HDD and SSD are perfectly healthy.

3.)  I have now gotten into the time wasteful rhythm of once a day or every other day having to boot from systemrescue cd and running `e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/root` to repair the file system so that I can do some type of work. (I have done disk integrity checks that find no problems.)

I was previously using cpulimit to control gnome-shell , vbox, and FF cpu usage on the host machine and thought maybe that was interfering with vbox I/O operations & causing "read-only file systems" errors, but de-activating cpulimit and creating a new vdi for my data, still gets me to the same errors in a few days.

**My question:**
Is there a better virtualization combination that will result in more reliable disks that someone can recommend? (i.e. using VDK on QEMU/VMplayer, etc, etc.?)

**NOTE:**
There is one unique thing about my setup that seems inconsequential to me.  My VDI is in a different location than the machine folder.  The machine folder is on an external USD, while the VDI is on my host machine's internal SSD.

I consider this inconsequential because the problem stilled occurs when I have VM & VDI on my internal HHD storage (home) drive and/or solely on the external storage.  I moved the VDI (via vbox functionality) as to take advantage of the SSD and try to get a faster boot times.

Machine Profile:

Machine Brand

```
$sudo dmidecode | less | grep "Product Name"
    Product Name: Aspire A515-55G
    Product Name: Doc_IL
```

Memory:

```
$ sudo lshw -short -C memory
H/W path             Device          Class          Description
===============================================================
/0/0                                 memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4/6                               memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/4/7                               memory         2MiB L2 cache
/0/4/8                               memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/5                                 memory         192KiB L1 cache
/0/f                                 memory         20GiB System Memory
/0/f/0                               memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/f/1                               memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/100/14.2                          memory         RAM memory
```

Complete Hardware Profile:

Pastebin  (too long for Ubuntu)

https://pastebin.com/2y6tmGQF

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135296/discussion-on-question-by-nightwatch-virtualization-advice-sought).